# How do I list the meta-data in a font file?

Tags: fonts, file-metadata

I have some font file (specifically, a TrueType, .tff, file) which I want to examine. I can run:

```
file myfont.ttf
```

and get something like:

```
TrueType Font data, 15 tables, 1st "OS/2", 24 names, Unicode
```

but I'm sure there must be more, such as:

- Font family name(s)
- License
- Weight
- Whether it's an Italic font or not
- Copyright notice
- Copyright year / publication year

etc.

How can I get all, or at least more, of this meta-data printed?

Assume a relatively recent Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fc-query` (for font-cache-query):

```
fc-query my_font.ttf
```

gets you a lot of the fields you asked for, and others, e.g.:

```
Pattern has 22 elts (size 32)
    family: "My Nice Family"(s)
    style: "Regular"(s)
    fullname: "My Nice Family Black"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 0(f)(s)
    width: 100(f)(s)
    foundry: "TheFoundary"(s)
    file: "my_fonts.ttf"(s)
    index: 0(i)(s)
    outline: True(s)
    scalable: True(s)
    charset: 
--snip--
(s)
    lang: aa|af|av|ay|be|bg|bi|br|bs|ca|ce|ch|co|cs|cy|da|de|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fo|fr|fur|fy|gd|gl|gv|he|ho|hr|hu|ia|id|ie|ik|io|is|it|ki|kl|kum|la|lb|lez|lt|lv|mg|mh|mt|nb|nds|nl|nn|no|nr|nso|ny|oc|om|os|pl|pt|rm|ru|se|sel|sk|sl|sma|smj|smn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|sv|sw|tk|tl|tn|tr|ts|uk|uz|vo|vot|wa|wen|wo|xh|yap|yi|zu|an|crh|csb|fil|hsb|ht|jv|kj|ku-tr|kwm|lg|li|ms|na|ng|pap-an|pap-aw|rn|rw|sc|sg|sn|su|za(s)
    fontversion: 65536(i)(s)
    fontformat: "TrueType"(s)
    decorative: False(s)
    postscriptname: "MyNiceFamilyBlack"(s)
    color: False(s)
    symbol: False(s)
    variable: False(s)
    fonthashint: True(s)
    order: 0(i)(s)
```

Comment: im building an electron app with js. u know of any good frameworks to access the metadata of all or many font file types (e.g. otf, ttf, woff, woff2, etc)?

Comment: @oldboy: Not really, perhaps you should ask this on SO or SR.SX .

Comment: how do I know possible values of `style` attribute

Comment: @silentsudo: I'm not sure there's a closed set of possible values. But "Italic", "Bold" "Semibold", "Black", "Light" are words you're likely to find in there.

Comment: @einpoklum think i found one that should be sufficient until i figure out how to code it myself. thx nonetheless <3

Comment: @oldboy can you share your findings